# Compute an expectation value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,...,X_n\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \theta)$ be iid. Define $Y=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2$ where $\overline X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

I want to compute $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$ and cannot seem to get to a reasonable result. Can something about how $Y$ must be distributed be said? I don't think I can compute the expectation purely algebraically.

EDIT: I could now proceed and I am almost done.

Since we have that $\mathbb{E}[S_n^2]=\theta$ for $S_n^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline X)$

it follows that $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{n-1}{n}\theta$ which is correct.

For $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$ I will try a similar approach using the translation theorem $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]=Var[Y]+(\mathbb{E}[Y])^2$.

I know that $Var[S_n^2]=1/n(3\theta^2 -\frac{n-3}{n-1}\theta^2)$ This follows from here: [StackExchange Post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29905/reference-for-mathrmvars2-sigma4-left-frac2n-1-frac-kappan)

We then have that

$\mathbb{E}[Y^2]= 1/n(3\theta^2 -\frac{n-3}{n-1}\theta^2) + \theta^2=\frac{\theta^2}{n^2}(\frac{n^2(n+1)}{n-1})$

Because I can transform between $S_n^2$ and $Y$ by applying a factor $(n-1)/n$.

However, this is incorrect, it should be $\frac{\theta^2}{n^2}(n^2-1)$

Comment: It's a little easier to try to compute $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2$. This is a standard calculation that is any book on statistics, but if I remember correctly is kind of messy. I believe you will be able to reproduce it if you fix the first pre-factor as I put it.

Comment: @DavidJaramillo YES, thats it! We have $E[Y]=(n-1)/n\theta$. and this leads to the correct result. Any idea for $E[Y^2]$?

Comment: Hmm I mean I am not quite sure, but the thing one usually do is to get the distribution of $Y$ (or rather $\frac{n-1}{n} Y$) which is kind of messy and then you can compute any of the moments. In particular $E[Y^2]$. I don't remember having done this caluclation, but once you have the pdf it can be done.

Comment: I kept thinking about this. I did remember $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2$ behaves as a $\chi^2$ with $n-1$ degrees of freedom (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) you cand then compute the moments you are interested in. I remember it was quite messy so I wont try to reproduce it, but I guess if you google it, you will be able to find it

Comment: @DavidJaramillo Thanks for this relation. I never knew there is a connection between Normals centered around sample mean and $\chi^2$ distribution.